# Change the ConnectionString from a online tutorial

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, connection-string, app-config

I was watching a pluralsight tutorial and in order to execute the code, i have to redo the connection string.

```
<add name="CodedHomesDEV" connectionString="Data Source=STORMSHADOW\SQLSERVER;Initial 
Catalog=CodedHomesDEV;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I guess i have to change the data source, but i have no idea what to replace.

Any help?

Comment: Yes, you should put there the instance name of the sql server instance that you want to connect. http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ and [How to: Connect to a SQL Server Database Using the SqlDataSource Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: If it's default sql server installment then changing `STORMSHADOW\SQLSERVER` to just `.\SQLSERVER` should work. If not then `STORMSHADOW` is the name of computer and you should look for yours - this should work only for local database connection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the Data Source with the named or default instance of the SQL Server that your local copy of the database CodedHomesDEV is in. You don't need to change anything else in your connectionstring assuming you haven't changed the name of the database CodedHomesDEV.

If you have, then change the Initial Catalog to the newly named database.